# How to access an array from an AngularJS template

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to display images in a list. The path to the image is stored in an array called `imagesUrls`.

`imagesUrls['dhd.png'] = "./img/brands/dhd.png"
imagesUrls['channelislands.png'] = "./img/brands/channelislands.png"`

etc...

```
<ion-item collection-repeat="item in prodataSelect | unique:'brand' | orderBy:'brand'" collection-item-height="75" >
   <img class="selectBrandImage" ng-src="imagesUrls['{{item.brand | nospace | lowercase}}.png']" />
   <span classs="selectBrandName">{{item.brand}}</span>
</ion-item>
```

controllers.js:

```
prodata = sessionService.get('prodata');
$scope.prodataSelect = prodata;
$scope.imagesUrls = sessionService.get('imagesUrls');
```

I can't find the right syntax for the `ng-src` in the template, can you help please ?

I also tried this:

```
ng-src="getImgPath(item.brand)"
```

with this:

```
$scope.getImgPath = function(str) {
   return imagesUrls[$filter('nospace')($filter('lowercase')(str))];
}
```

Comment: What is the value of src when you inspect the element in your browser? Do you have a fiddle that we can play with?

Comment: When I inspect the value is src="imagesUrls['carroll.png']"

Comment: Have you tried with src instead of ng-src?

Comment: with src instead of ng-src, I get the same result in the src when I inspect

Comment: How is the image array related to the `prodata` object? By order?

Comment: not really, it's a bit complicated, the image array has several types of images. I think I found a solution

Answer (score 1):

It works with this:

```
ng-src="{{getImgPath(item.brand)}}"
```

and

```
 $scope.getImgPath = function(str) {
    str = $filter('nospace')($filter('lowercase')(str));
    str = str + ".png";
    return $scope.imagesUrls[str];
  }
```